# How to insert data using CI active record to field names with space?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How to insert data to the fields with name containing space.
eg :

```
$data = array(
    "First Name" => "Bob",
    "Email ID" => "bob@example.com"
);
$this->db->insert("table_name", $data);
```

Insert batch is also not working.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        "First Name" => "Bob",
        "Email ID" => "bob@example.com"
    ),
    array(
        "First Name" => "Joe",
        "Email ID" => "Joe@example.com"
    )
);
$this->db->insert_batch("table_name", $data);
```

Comment: This practice is one of those added on "what not to do"... [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14190833/1057527) might give you an idea how to do manage space in column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code. Which worked for me. use `$db->set` method

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{
$this->db->set($key, $val);
}
$this->db->insert('table_name');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll check. I used static SQL using `$this->db->query()` for fixing the issue :)

Comment: I have checked in my local system. Working perfectly

Comment: And where is the batch?

Comment: Loop the insert stmt accordingly

Answer (score 0):

for me ...

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{
$this->db->set($key, $val);
}
$this->db->insert('table_name');
```

.. changed nothing! :(

«Adj Close» gets to «'Adj' 'Close'» in the query. with ' as `.

So I had to do this:

```
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    if (strstr($k," ")){
       $this->db->set('`'.addslashes($k).'`', $v, false);
       unset($data[$k]);
    }
}
$returnDB = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
```

then it worked!