# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, sql, warnings, mariadb

I keep getting the error:-

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Password='evertonblues' Forename='Josh' Surname='Edmondson'
>   `Date of Birth`='199' at line 1"

error when running my update query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Users SET Username='".$newUsername."' Password='".$newPassword."' Forename='".$newForename."' Surname='".$newSurname."' `Date of Birth`='".$newDateofBirth."'     Address='".$newAddress."' `Post Code`='".$newPostcode."' Email='".$newEmail."' `Phone Number`='".$newPhonenumber."' WHERE `User ID`='".$newUserid."';");
```

Comment: I updated the question, code should now be there

Comment: It could be related to escaping the column name `Date of Birth`, which contains spaces. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14190798/1749822

Comment: Followed some suggestions in the linked thread, still no use :/

Comment: Missing a comma between username and password; and many others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a bunch of commas:

```
..snip... SET Username='".$newUsername."' Password='".$newPassw
                                         ^-- and many others
```

Comment: The commas did the trick boss, nice observation, im new to PHP and have spent hours on end looking at this code :P

Comment: Nothing to do with php, really. that's purely an sql-level problem. php just happens to be a wrapper around that sql

Answer (score 1):

Use query as below:

```
"UPDATE Users SET `Username`='".$newUsername."', `Password`='".$newPassword."', `Forename`='".$newForename."', `Surname`='".$newSurname."', `Date of Birth`='".$newDateofBirth."', `Address`='".$newAddress."', `Post Code`='".$newPostcode."', `Email`='".$newEmail."', `Phone Number`='".$newPhonenumber."' WHERE `User ID`='".$newUserid."';");
```

Also space in `Date of Birth`

Comment: Spaces don't matter. It's properly escaped with back tics.  If they did matter `Post Code` would also be a problem.

Comment: This one worked, thank you so much, just spent the last 3 hours getting annoyed over my code, im new to PHP too so that doesn't help :P