# How to run a query on a table that has colon in its name?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, query-string

I'm reading data from an .mdb file (MSAccess 2000 format). There are some tables that have colons in their names. I'm getting an exception when I try to open queries on these tables:

```
EOleException with message 'Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided'.
```

this is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Query: TADOQuery;
begin
  Query := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  Query.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+
    'Data Source=DB.mdb;Persist Security Info=False';
  Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from [Table1:1]';
  try
    Query.Open;
  finally
    Query.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TQuery` will interpret the `:` [if `ParamCheck = true`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBTables_TQuery_ParamCheck.html).
Set `ParamCheck:= false` and then set the `SQL.Text`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Query: TADOQuery;
begin
  Query := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  Query.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+
    'Data Source=DB.mdb;Persist Security Info=False';
  Query.ParamCheck:= false;
  Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from [Table1:1]';
  try
    Query.Open;
  finally
    Query.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now it works.

**Combining coloned table/column names and parameters**
If you absolutely must go down the path of using table/column names with colons in them and still want to use params elsewhere in your query then you can use a macro to fill in the table/column name.
This requires FireDac though. 
I do recommend you be very careful with this because unlike parameters macro's are not safe against SQL injection!

See:  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FireDAC.TFDQuery.Macros_Sample

Comment: Don't forget to remove any parameters that might have been added before. Check the `Parameters` property.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Doesn't setting `SQL.Text` automatically clear `Parameters`?

Comment: If you set ParamCheck to false, I think it doesn't. It just leaves the parameters alone so you can manage them yourself. 99% sure. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I was checking solutions in other languages. However [Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36957384/2093077) seems to be the right one, but the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190833/2093077) also works in Delphi/Access case:

Using backticks ` around your tablename should allow it to be ignored by the param check.

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from `Table1:1`';
```

This one also can be combined with using parameters in query string.

Comment: I don't know about Delphi, but MS Access *never* uses backticks. Table/field names with e.g. spaces always need [square brackets].

Comment: @Andre I just created a query inside MS Access 2007 and typed this query string in SQL view. It shows the result with no problem.

Comment: You're right (and I was wrong) - backticks can be used in place of square brackets. Surprising. :)  `SELECT [Tabelle1:1].ID, \`Tabelle1:1\`.\`nix:dings\`
FROM [Tabelle1:1];` works, without the backticks it doesn't.

Comment: Nice one. I guess TQuery special cases the backticks, but does not special case the `[`.