# How to deal with spaces in the columns while using SQL select

Tags: mysql, quoting

I have 3 columns in Database tables. Id Operator , o.Id Country

```
select [o.Id Operator] as OperatorID,[o.Id Country] as countryid
from 
customersubscription cs inner join club cl on (cs.idclub = cl.idclub) 
inner join customer cu on (cs.idcustomer = cu.idcustomer)
inner join operator o on (cu.idoperator = o.idoperator) 
left outer join promoter p on (cs.idpromoter = p.id )
where 
cl.idproject in (3,19,23,24,27)
```

The two columns in the select sections have spaces in them. I used `[ ]` and tried   as mentioned in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-space-between-in-mysql-on-liunx-ubuntu) but didnt work.

Comment: Which database are you using here? MySQL and SQLite are similar, but SQL Server is the one that uses `[...]`. Honestly, spaces are super annoying, so the best way is to get rid of them and alter your schema.

Comment: I am not allowed to edit. Ihave read only access. Its MySQL

Comment: That's a tough break.

Comment: IS there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL any column name that isn't simple (composed of letters, numbers, and/or underscores) must be escaped:

```
SELECT o.`Id Operator` as OperatorID,
  o.`Id Country` as countryid
```

If you're calling the one `OperatorID`, the next should be `CountryID` for consistency's sake.

Comment: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.31-log]Unknown column 'o.Id Operator' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you sure you put the backticks in the right place? Are you sure that's the right column name? You can check with `DESCRIBE operator`.

Comment: How do I check with the describe operator please?

Comment: Based on your question `operator` is the table in question. If you want a visual tool to help with this, [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is pretty good and free.

Comment: Well, the name is okay, ` `s are placed on the right place as well. What can be the problem

Comment: This is how you escape things. As to what's wrong, I don't know. Maybe that column's not right. Maybe it has *two* spaces.

Comment: @Ahmed, the error message in the earlier comment, `Unknown column 'o.Id Operator' ` *strongly* suggests incorrect backtick placement of `\`o.Id Operator\`` instead of correct placement, which would be `o.\`Id Operator\``.  The error shown can really have no other explanation.

Comment: Something strange. I type o.``Id Operator`` but in the error it shows ``o.Id Operator``

Answer (score 0):

You *can* quote column names with `[`/`]` in SQLite, but then anythying between the brackets will be part of the column name.

So the column name you a trying to use is `o.Id Operator`.

The period that separates the table name and the column name must not be quoted. And in MySQL, you must use backticks instead:

```
SELECT o.`Id Operator` ...
```

Comment: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.31-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Id Operator] as OperatorID,o.[Id Country] as countryid, cl.name as project, cl.' at line 3

Comment: was lazy to type