# Cannot fill a Combobox in a Datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a project and it need to choose database list on Combobox and show it in Datagridview. Here is my code :

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source= D:\Database\đồ án\Đồ án.mdb");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Sheet1", con);
                da.Fill(dt);
                da.Dispose();

                comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Tên đề tài";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "Mã đề tài";
            }

 private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source= D:\Database\đồ án\Đồ án.mdb");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Sheet11 Where Mã đề tài = "+comboBox1.SelectedValue, con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

When I run this program and click on Combobox, it shows an error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7DdZ.png

At first, I thought 2 sheets (tables) in database was not showing and didn't relationship but when I make it done and tried to start again, it shows an error again. How can I fix it ?

Comment: [Does the column name contain spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-space-between-in-mysql-on-liunx-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, the column name has a spaces

Comment: So they need to be enclosed by either apostophes or brackets. (The comment was not a question really, but a link)

Answer (score 2):

2 important notes:

1. Use parameters not string concatenation
2. It is bad practice to use spaces on column names. If you do, use brackets

Considering the above, try:

```
string query="Select * from Sheet11 Where [Mã đề tài] = @param";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@param", comboBox1.SelectedValue))
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. Mmmmm, when i click on a combobox it need to show a database list and help you chosen a database and it showed in datagridview .

Comment: It showed :" No value given for one or more required parameters "

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: When asking here it really matters exatcly what errors you get. So telling us : _It shows an error again_ is pretty much useless. But see my answer for the 2nd error you get, after correcting the spaces-error..

Comment: Sorry, my bad :(

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the *'spaces in column names'* error you also got the **order** of the binding wrong when you set up the `ComboBox`.

You need to **first** set the **members** and only **then** the **datasource**. So change

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Tên đề tài";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Mã đề tài";
```

to:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Tên đề tài";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Mã đề tài";
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Now not the whole table is bound but only the columns you want.

Before, the `SelectedValue` was not a single value but a whole `DataRowView` from which you would have to select the right item/column..

And, since it was a reference object, casting it to string (either implicitly with the `+` operator or explicitly with a `ToString` call) only resulted in the **class name** `System.Data.DataRowView` instead of a data value.

Further notes:

- Avoid spaces in names of any kind; some moderen systems may work with them, but it will make the code less robust. The same goes for non-ascii characters.
- While the values in your query here are only coming from the database, it is recommended to only use parameterized queries to avoid any **sql injection**.
- Since you already have loaded the data into the `DataTable` you could just as well **filter** them without going back to the data base again. For this create a `BindingSource` or a `DataView` with a `RowFilter` and bind the DGV to it. For this, make the `DataTable` a **class variable**.

Comment: It's not works, but i try to ask my teacher about this error. Thank you so much for help me fix this error .