# using spaces in columns names in sql to create table

Tags: sql, mariadb, quoted-identifier

I am trying to create table by sqlyog
i want to use spaces in columns names but i still got errors
for example id number
i just can do it like this id_number
i searched in this website i found two ways 
[id number] or "id number"
i tried it but i still have errors

this is the code

```
   CREATE TABLE project(
ProjectID VARCHAR(10),
Project NAME VARCHAR(50),
Group_Name VARCHAR(20),
BeginDate VARCHAR(10),
EndDate VARCHAR(10)
);
```

and these are the errors that i got them

```
   1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: CREATE table project( ProjectID varchar(10), Project Name varchar(50), Group_Name varchar(20), BeginDate varchar(10), EndDate va...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name varchar(50),
Group_Name varchar(20),
BeginDate varchar(10),
EndDate varc' at line 3
```

i hope some one helping me

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-a-space-in-mysql

Comment: Are you sure you do want it? Cannot it create future maintenance pain? Keep it simple and stupid

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Standard defines double quote character `"` to delimit identifiers.
Speaking of MariaDB and MySQL this requires that the `sql_mode` was set to `ANSI`:

```
mysql> set sql_mode=ANSI;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table project("project name" varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Another option (as mentioned in the previous answer) is to use backticks. However this solution will not be portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create tables and columns with spaces in the name using backticks (`)

Egg:

```
CREATE TABLE `project project` 
(
`ProjectID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`Project NAME` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    .
    .
    .
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
CREATE TABLE project(
ProjectID VARCHAR(10),
`Project NAME` VARCHAR(50),
Group_Name VARCHAR(20),
BeginDate VARCHAR(10),
EndDate VARCHAR(10)
);
```