# 1064 error while operating MySQL database with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to write a program in Python to control MySQL database, but the following error occurs

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; chec
k the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'Code,type, number,Whether )VALUES ('cl8k-k520-fg45-d4sa-sd9k','n' at line 1")
```

Code：

```
import pymysql 
db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS(Activation Code, \
       type, number,Whether ) \
       VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
data = [("cl8k-k520-fg45-d4sa-sd9k",'n','10','n'),
        ("jhg6-58jh-gh8o-8uik-7jk8",'c','20','n'),
        ("x5hg-gf5h-4hj5-g4h5-fh5t",'y','999','n'),
        ("fg8j-h584-fd4g-fg4d-fgg4",'n','1','y'),
        ("4jk4-5kl4-4klk-4lji-4ghj",'e','6','n'),
        ]
cursor.executemany(sql,data)
db.close()
```

This is my first time to ask questions on this platform. I hope to get answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a column name with a space in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-a-space-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose `Activation Code` as `'Activation Code'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll never make a mistake again