# creating the table in MySQL with name spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

While creating the table with name spaces using MySQL Database, it's throwing the below error.

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[school name] VARCHAR(20))' at line 1**

Here is my simple table creation of the code :

```
create table table_dump(name varchar(20), address varchar(20), [school name] varchar(20));

 or

create table table_dump(name varchar(20), address varchar(20), "school name" varchar(20));
```

Comment: Don't do it!  Use underscores instead.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, isn't possible to create column name with spaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a column name with a space in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-a-space-in-mysql)

Comment: yes you use backticks around the name.  With that said, developers and anyone maintaining your code will hate you for doing this.

Comment: It is possible but explicitly bad practice

Comment: @user98 . . . It is *possible*.  That doesn't mean it is desirable or recommended.

Comment: Including spaces or mathematical operators within table names sis simply a cataclysmically bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backticks around the name.

```
create table table_dump(name varchar(20), address varchar(20), `school name` varchar(20));
```

The same goes for the use of MySQL keywords as many people for example might want to name a column in a table `date` or `datetime`, and you will have a similar issue if you try and do this without the backticks.  Many people, and all relational design tools that generate DDL will add backticks around all table and column names for this exact reason.

With all this stated, don't use spaces in your names.  That is a poor standard and hard to read and maintain.  As an unofficial standard, use underscores between the words in your table and column names.

Comment: yes it's working fine. But is it good practice to use  backticks.

Comment: is it good practice to use backticks? - you don't have a choice if you use whitespaces in column names or reserved words.

Comment: Many people use them in all cases, so I would say it probably is best practice.  If you execute a `show create table {tablename}` you will see that mysql generates them regardless of what the original DDL is.  With that said, in most cases, you run the DDL once, so if you know the rules and the DDL works, that's all that really matters.