# MySQL table value execution

Tags: mysql

I am doing a simple execution in MySQL workbench, the syntax is correct but nothing is happening.

```sql
select first name from employees;
```

only that but nothing is happening on the table. can someone what might be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a column name with a space in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-a-space-in-mysql)

Comment: You should NEVER EVER have a space in your column names.  Very poor database design.