CSV file not uploading to the SQL database and PHP code not defining the values properly
My PHP code is not uploading data that is being inserted to my SQL database. I have had different source have looked for different fixes for this problem, but I cannot seem to find a fix for it. I have fiddle with the code but there is not fixes around this problem that I am able to find. Is there a more efficient way to comparing the csv values to the columns they are being inserted in? Without the require_once("html-4coumn.php") the upload.php outputs an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''COL 1', 'COL 2', 'COL 3', 'COL 4', 'COL 5', 'COL 6', 'COL 7', 'COL 8', 'COL ...' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ds\upload.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ds\upload.php(16): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO air...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ds\upload.php on line 16
The code does not produce the output of  "CSV File has been successfully Imported." or "Invalid File: Please Upload CSV File." I have had a look at similar solution especially: large csv file not uploaded to database but I can't find a solution. Also thank you for the comments telling me that my SQL is at risk I understand this. This is a test website and will NOT be up and running physically. I am still learning the secure way of doing this.

upload.php
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","taw") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

require_once("html-4column.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];    
     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
          while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
           {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO airport ('COL 1', 'COL 2', 'COL 3', 'COL 4', 'COL 5', 'COL 6', 'COL 7', 'COL 8', 'COL 9', 'COL 10', 'COL 11', 'COL 12') 
             VALUES ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."','".$getData[5]."','".$getData[6]."','".$getData[7]."','".$getData[8]."','".$getData[9]."','".$getData[10]."','".$getData[11]."')";
                   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(!isset($result))
        {
          echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
              alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
              window.location = \"html4-column.php\"
              </script>";    
        }
        else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
            window.location = \"html4-column.php\"
          </script>";
        }
           }
      
           fclose($file);  
     }
  } 

?>


    <div>
        
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="upload.php" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <fieldset>
                        <!-- Form Name -->
                        <legend>Airport data upload</legend>
                        <!-- File Button -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Select File</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="file">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Import data</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn-submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Import</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>

    </div>


How is this problem related to HTML?  Also, be warned that your INSERT query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacke

Since you have a space in your column names use backticks: `COL 1` not single quotes.
For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190833/5470728

Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

@SalimIbrohimi can you put this as a solution if anyone else comes across this post because it has fixed my problem. Thank you.
